# how to stretch unordered lists with scrollbar to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to make one of my web pages prettier.

The page has a couple of lists that can have anywhere from 0 to 500+ elements. The lists start from different levels / y-coordinate. How can I adjust the height of the lists so that they get stretched to occupy the rest of the height in the browser, along with the page's footer? Kind of like an email client with email folders and emails listed side-by-side as scrollable lists.

Is it possible to do it without complex calculations involving heights of elements above the lists?

Here is the sample page I created to clarify the question:
http://jsfiddle.net/dilipvshah/gh2Au/

CSS

```
.header {
    width: 800px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px black; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
}
.footer {
    width: 800px; height: 20px; border: solid 1px black; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
}
.subHeader {
    display: table-cell; height: 50px; text-align: center;
}
.content {
    display: table; width: 800px; text-align: center;
}
.contentInner {
    display: table-row; width: 100%; text-align: center;
}
.contentLeft {
    display: table-cell; width: 30%; border: solid 1px black; text-align: center;
}
.contentRight {
    display: table-cell; height: 400px; border: solid 1px black; text-align: center;
}
.tableLayout {
    display: table; width: 100%;
}
.tableRowLayout {
    display: table-row; width: 100%;
}
.listLeft {
    list-style: none; text-align: left; max-height: 500px; overflow-y:auto;
}
.listRight {
    list-style: none; text-align: left; max-height: 500px; overflow-y:auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Header
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="contentInner">
            <div class="contentLeft">
                Left
                <ul id="leftList" class="listLeft">
                   <li> ... </li>
                   [ ... ]
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="tableLayout">
                <div class="tableRowLayout">
                    <div class="subHeader">
                        Sub-header
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tableRowLayout">
                    <div class="contentRight">
                        Right
                        <ul id="rightList" class="listRight">
                            <li> ... </li>
                            [ ... ]
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>

</body>
```

Adding an image to clarify the question.
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify, do you want the `li`s to change height, or the `ul` to not extend past the bottom of the page (so the header is always visible), or some other way of occupying the space? Your demo currently does occupy the full space (and then some) because there's a bunch of `li`s.

Comment: I think what he's after is that the content of the page should never go "below the fold", so for instance if there where a footer as well as a header both would always be onscreen. So the lists should be columns of equal height, but never cause the footer to be pushed down "below the fold" causing scrollbars to show up on the page (the scrollbars should be added on the lists instead. This is mere speculation though, so please correct me if I'm wrong @Dilip

Comment: @Hummlas, quite in line with your description but the lists start at different y-coordinates and so have different heights. What I'm trying to achieve is for the lists to automatically set their heights such that when necessary, they become scrollable and when you add the height of the footer, the web page is flushed to the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is to use `position:absolute` with `top:0;bottom:0` to ensure that the lists exactly fill up the remaining window height.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/gh2Au/7/)**

Note:

- I have removed the markup/css connected with tables. (This reduces a lot of the markup and css)
- The javascript in the fiddle has nothing to do with the layout - it's just to create the dummy lists' content

Comment: This may get me closer to what I'm looking for but is it possible to achieve the same without absolute positioning? My Page is quite complex and the elements above the lists may have variable heights.